# I am not able to understand what this piece of code is doing. can anyone please explain?

Tags: r, data.table

```
excelTbl[, .(sum(`Current Period Amount`),
               sum(`Comparison Period Amount`),
               sum(`% Change`),
               type = if (sum(`Current Period Amount`) - sum(`Comparison Period Amount`)< 0) "N" else "P"),
           by = .(Class, AccountSubType)][round(V1) != 0 &
                                            round(V2) != 0 &
                                            (if (logicalOp == 1) {
                                              ((abs(V2 - V1) * 100 / abs(V2)) >= variancePer) &
                                                #(abs(V3)*100 >= variancePer) &
                                                (abs(V2 - V1) >= varianceAmt * 1000000)
                                            } else {
                                              ((abs(V2 - V1) * 100 / abs(V2)) >= variancePer) |
                                                #(abs(V3)*100 >= variancePer) |
                                                (abs(V2 - V1) >= varianceAmt * 1000000)
                                            }), 1:2]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, it helps if you can format code better (I've edited for basic layout).

Comment: What part of this is not clear to you? Is it the basic `data.table` syntax of `.(something)`? The `by=.(...)`?

Comment: Have you broken it up by brackets to see what each step is doing? For instance, just run `excelTbl[, .(sum...), by=.(Class, AccountSubType)]`, store that in a temp variable, then try the next batch?

Comment: @r2evans I am not able to understand what the second pair of square brackets is doing. Basically, the part after 'by'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `round(V1) != 0` returns a `logical` vector as long as there are rows in the table. For example,

   ```r
   1:5 < 3
   # [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```
2. `... & round(V2) != 0` is a vectorized "AND", where it is still as long as there are rows in the table. For example,

   ```r
   (1:5 < 3) & (6:10 < 7)
   # [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```
3. `if (logicalOp == 1) ... else ...` will calculate one of two `logical` vectors based on the value of `logicalOp`. If it is 1, then it logically "AND"s the `logical` vector returned from

   ```r
   ((abs(V2 - V1) * 100 / abs(V2)) >= variancePer) &
     (abs(V2 - V1) >= varianceAmt * 1000000)
   ```

   otherwise the other vector.

   This is vector-wise "AND"ed with the results of the two `round` logical vectors.

   And because all of that is before the first comma (it is in the `i=` component of the bracket indexing), it defined which rows to return. If you have a logical vector as long as there are rows, then the rows with `TRUE` will be preserved, `FALSE` will be discarded.

   While many things in `data.table` operate in-place (*referential semantics*, as opposed to R's regular *copy-on-write semantics*), anything that subsets the rows like this will return another `data.table` object and not modify the original in-place. Because of this, the value of this code chunk should be captured into a new variable.
4. After the comma, `1:2` selects the first two columns.

   Interestingly, the first bracket block creates a `data.table` with six columns, named `Class` and `AccountSubType` (the groups defined with `by=`), `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, and `type`. However, the second bracket block only references `V1` and `V2` in the filtering and then discards all except `Class` and `AccountSubType`, so ... it seems there is unnecessary calculation.

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thank you so much for your quick resposnse! 
@r2evans  Also, I'm getting and error when I try to execute the second block of code. It says, error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) : 
  Object 'logicalOp' not found amongst Class, AccountSubType, V1, V2, V3 and 1 more

Comment: I think that error speaks for itself ... all this means is that `logicalOp` has not been defined *anywhere* (most likely in the surrounding environment and not within the `data.table`). I'm inferring that you are inheriting this code from elsewhere, I suggest you look at the code for un-executed portions or reach out to the author(s) for clarification.

Comment: you are correct. This snippet is a part of a bigger portion of code. I'll go through that code once and try to understand where logicalOp is being defined! Thanks for your help! I totally understood the code snippet through your answer though! :)